# Firebase - adding document with id mismatch?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Seen a few posts about this but I'm not getting the results I had hoped for.
Plan: Pass the document id to the item as a field.

```
const ref = db.collection('mycollection').doc();
console.log(ref.id);
db.collection('mycollection').add({
    id: ref.id,
    name: req.body.name
})
.then(docRef => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
```

When I run this (`firebase serve` and send data via Postman) the *ref.id* and *docRef.id* do not match, eg:

```
zR5nJ348OpbwHcyGoojC
info: Document written with ID:  Fh2mqfZKpizzW5RIJ0yF
```

I expected them to match - was this incorrect of me?

If they aren't going to match then I could always do an update on the item I've just created but that feels unnecessary.

The reason I am doing this is so I can easily update or delete an item by referencing the ID directly. But I'm open to other suggestions in case I'm barking up the wrong bush.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `doc()` (without arguments) or `add(...)`, Firestore will create a new document ID. Since you're calling both in your code, you end up with two separate IDs. The trick is to only call one or the other, like:

```
const ref = db.collection('mycollection').doc();
ref.set({
    id: ref.id,
    name: req.body.name
})
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you :) 
And for anyone else watching at home, the Promise returns something different: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.20.x/WriteResult